# PySpark ALSModel load fails in deployment over Azure ML service with error java.util.NoSuchElementException: Param blockSize does not exist

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to deploy an ALS model trained using PySpark on Azure ML service. I am providing a score.py file that loads the trained model using ALSModel.load() function. Following is the code of my score.py file.

```
import os
from azureml.core.model import Model
from pyspark.ml.recommendation import ALS, ALSModel
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType, StringType
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
spark = sqlContext.sparkSession

input_schema = StructType([StructField("UserId", StringType())])
reader = spark.read
reader.schema(input_schema)


def init():
    global model
    # note here "iris.model" is the name of the model registered under the workspace
    # this call should return the path to the model.pkl file on the local disk.
    model_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('AZUREML_MODEL_DIR'), "recommendation-model")
    # Load the model file back into a LogisticRegression model
    model = ALSModel.load(model_path)
    

def run(data):
    try:
        input_df = reader.json(sc.parallelize([data]))
        input_df = indexer.transform(input_df)
        
        res = model.recommendForUserSubset(input_df[['UserId_index']], 10)

        # you can return any datatype as long as it is JSON-serializable
        return result.collect()[0]['recommendations']
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        error = str(e)
        return error
```

Following is the error I get when I deploy it as LocalWebService using Model.deploy function in Azure ML service

```
Generating Docker build context.
Package creation Succeeded
Logging into Docker registry viennaglobal.azurecr.io
Logging into Docker registry viennaglobal.azurecr.io
Building Docker image from Dockerfile...
Step 1/5 : FROM viennaglobal.azurecr.io/azureml/azureml_43542b56c5ec3e8d0f68e1556558411f
 ---> 5b3bb174ca5f
Step 2/5 : COPY azureml-app /var/azureml-app
 ---> 8e540c0746f7
Step 3/5 : RUN mkdir -p '/var/azureml-app' && echo eyJhY2NvdW50Q29udGV4dCI6eyJzdWJzY3JpcHRpb25JZCI6IjNkN2M1ZjM4LTI1ODEtNGUxNi05NTdhLWEzOTU1OGI1ZjBiMyIsInJlc291cmNlR3JvdXBOYW1lIjoiZGV2LW9tbmljeC10ZnMtYWkiLCJhY2NvdW50TmFtZSI6ImRldi10ZnMtYWktd29ya3NwYWNlIiwid29ya3NwYWNlSWQiOiI1NjkzNGMzNC1iZmYzLTQ3OWUtODRkMy01OGI4YTc3ZTI4ZjEifSwibW9kZWxzIjp7fSwibW9kZWxzSW5mbyI6e319 | base64 --decode > /var/azureml-app/model_config_map.json
 ---> Running in 502ad8edf91e
 ---> a1bc5e0283d0
Step 4/5 : RUN mv '/var/azureml-app/tmpvxhomyin.py' /var/azureml-app/main.py
 ---> Running in eb4ec1a0b702
 ---> 6a3296fe6420
Step 5/5 : CMD ["runsvdir","/var/runit"]
 ---> Running in 834fd746afef
 ---> 5b9f8be538c0
Successfully built 5b9f8be538c0
Successfully tagged recommend-service:latest
Container (name:musing_borg, id:0f3163692f5119685eee5ed59c8e00aa96cd472f765e7db67653f1a6ce852e83) cannot be killed.
Container has been successfully cleaned up.
Image sha256:0f146f4752878bbbc0e876f4477cc2877ff12a366fca18c986f9a9c2949d028b successfully removed.
Starting Docker container...
Docker container running.
Checking container health...
ERROR - Error: Container has crashed. Did your init method fail?


Container Logs:
/bin/bash: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
/bin/bash: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
/bin/bash: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
/bin/bash: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
2020-07-30T11:57:00,312735664+00:00 - rsyslog/run 
2020-07-30T11:57:00,312768364+00:00 - gunicorn/run 
2020-07-30T11:57:00,313017966+00:00 - iot-server/run 
bash: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by bash)
2020-07-30T11:57:00,313969073+00:00 - nginx/run 
/usr/sbin/nginx: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nginx)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nginx)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nginx)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nginx)
/usr/sbin/nginx: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/sbin/nginx)
EdgeHubConnectionString and IOTEDGE_IOTHUBHOSTNAME are not set. Exiting...
/bin/bash: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
2020-07-30T11:57:00,597835804+00:00 - iot-server/finish 1 0
2020-07-30T11:57:00,598826211+00:00 - Exit code 1 is normal. Not restarting iot-server.
Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:31311 (10)
Using worker: sync
worker timeout is set to 300
Booting worker with pid: 41
bash: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by bash)
bash: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by bash)
Ivy Default Cache set to: /root/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /root/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/mmlspark/lib/spark/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
com.microsoft.ml.spark#mmlspark_2.11 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-e07358bb-d354-4f41-aa4c-f0aa73bb0156;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found com.microsoft.ml.spark#mmlspark_2.11;0.15 in spark-list
    found io.spray#spray-json_2.11;1.3.2 in central
    found com.microsoft.cntk#cntk;2.4 in central
    found org.openpnp#opencv;3.2.0-1 in central
    found com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.54 in central
    found org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.5.6 in central
    found org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.4.10 in central
    found commons-logging#commons-logging;1.2 in central
    found commons-codec#commons-codec;1.10 in central
    found com.microsoft.ml.lightgbm#lightgbmlib;2.1.250 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 318ms :: artifacts dl 11ms
    :: modules in use:
    com.jcraft#jsch;0.1.54 from central in [default]
    com.microsoft.cntk#cntk;2.4 from central in [default]
    com.microsoft.ml.lightgbm#lightgbmlib;2.1.250 from central in [default]
    com.microsoft.ml.spark#mmlspark_2.11;0.15 from spark-list in [default]
    commons-codec#commons-codec;1.10 from central in [default]
    commons-logging#commons-logging;1.2 from central in [default]
    io.spray#spray-json_2.11;1.3.2 from central in [default]
    org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.5.6 from central in [default]
    org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.4.10 from central in [default]
    org.openpnp#opencv;3.2.0-1 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   10  |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   10  |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
    unknown resolver repo-1

    unknown resolver repo-1


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-e07358bb-d354-4f41-aa4c-f0aa73bb0156
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 10 already retrieved (0kB/7ms)
2020-07-30 11:57:02 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Initialized PySpark session.
Initializing logger
2020-07-30 11:57:09,464 | root | INFO | Starting up app insights client
Starting up app insights client
2020-07-30 11:57:09,464 | root | INFO | Starting up request id generator
Starting up request id generator
2020-07-30 11:57:09,464 | root | INFO | Starting up app insight hooks
Starting up app insight hooks
2020-07-30 11:57:09,464 | root | INFO | Invoking user's init function
Invoking user's init function
2020-07-30 11:57:19,652 | root | ERROR | User's init function failed
User's init function failed
2020-07-30 11:57:19,656 | root | ERROR | Encountered Exception Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/azureml-server/aml_blueprint.py", line 163, in register
    main.init()
  File "/var/azureml-app/main.py", line 44, in init
    model = ALSModel.load(model_path)
  File "/home/mmlspark/lib/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py", line 362, in load
    return cls.read().load(path)
  File "/home/mmlspark/lib/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py", line 300, in load
    java_obj = self._jread.load(path)
  File "/home/mmlspark/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/mmlspark/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/mmlspark/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o64.load.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Param blockSize does not exist.
    at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params$$anonfun$getParam$2.apply(params.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params$$anonfun$getParam$2.apply(params.scala:729)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params$class.getParam(params.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.getParam(Pipeline.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$Metadata$$anonfun$setParams$1.apply(ReadWrite.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$Metadata$$anonfun$setParams$1.apply(ReadWrite.scala:589)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$Metadata.setParams(ReadWrite.scala:589)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$Metadata.getAndSetParams(ReadWrite.scala:572)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALSModel$ALSModelReader.load(ALS.scala:533)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Encountered Exception Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/azureml-server/aml_blueprint.py", line 163, in register
    main.init()
  File "/var/azureml-app/main.py", line 44, in init
    model = ALSModel.load(model_path)
  File "/home/mmlspark/lib/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py", line 362, in load
    return cls.read().load(path)
  File "/home/mmlspark/lib/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py", line 300, in load
    java_obj = self._jread.load(path)
  File "/home/mmlspark/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/home/mmlspark/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/mmlspark/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o64.load.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Param blockSize does not exist.
    at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params$$anonfun$getParam$2.apply(params.scala:729)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params$$anonfun$getParam$2.apply(params.scala:729)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.param.Params$class.getParam(params.scala:728)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.getParam(Pipeline.scala:42)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$Metadata$$anonfun$setParams$1.apply(ReadWrite.scala:591)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$Metadata$$anonfun$setParams$1.apply(ReadWrite.scala:589)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$Metadata.setParams(ReadWrite.scala:589)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.util.DefaultParamsReader$Metadata.getAndSetParams(ReadWrite.scala:572)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.recommendation.ALSModel$ALSModelReader.load(ALS.scala:533)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


Worker exiting (pid: 41)
Shutting down: Master
Reason: Worker failed to boot.
/bin/bash: /azureml-envs/azureml_7fbe163ce1d4208cd897650a64b7a54d/lib/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
2020-07-30T11:57:19,833136837+00:00 - gunicorn/finish 3 0
2020-07-30T11:57:19,834216245+00:00 - Exit code 3 is not normal. Killing image.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
WebserviceException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-d0992ae9d1c9> in <module>
      6 local_service = Model.deploy(workspace, "recommend-service", [register_model], inference_config, deployment_config)
      7 
----> 8 local_service.wait_for_deployment()

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/webservice/local.py in decorated(self, *args, **kwargs)
     69                 raise WebserviceException('Cannot call {}() when service is {}.'.format(func.__name__, self.state),
     70                                           logger=module_logger)
---> 71             return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
     72         return decorated
     73     return decorator

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/webservice/local.py in wait_for_deployment(self, show_output)
    601                                    self._container,
    602                                    health_url=self._internal_base_url,
--> 603                                    cleanup_if_failed=False)
    604 
    605             self.state = LocalWebservice.STATE_RUNNING

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/_model_management/_util.py in container_health_check(docker_port, container, health_url, cleanup_if_failed)
    745             # The container has started and crashed.
    746             _raise_for_container_failure(container, cleanup_if_failed,
--> 747                                          'Error: Container has crashed. Did your init method fail?')
    748 
    749         # The container hasn't crashed, so try to ping the health endpoint.

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/_model_management/_util.py in _raise_for_container_failure(container, cleanup, message)
   1258         cleanup_container(container)
   1259 
-> 1260     raise WebserviceException(message, logger=module_logger)
   1261 
   1262 

WebserviceException: WebserviceException:
    Message: Error: Container has crashed. Did your init method fail?
    InnerException None
    ErrorResponse 
{
    "error": {
        "message": "Error: Container has crashed. Did your init method fail?"
    }
}
```

However, the ALSModel.load() works fine when executed in a Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

1. Is your model registered in the workspace? AZUREML_MODEL_DIR only works for registered models. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.model?view=azure-ml-py#register-workspace--model-path--model-name--tags-none--properties-none--description-none--datasets-none--model-framework-none--model-framework-version-none--child-paths-none--sample-input-dataset-none--sample-output-dataset-none--resource-configuration-none-) for information about registering a model
2. Are you specifying the same version of pyspark.ml.recommendation in your InferenceConfig as you use locally? This kind of error might be due to a difference in versions
3. Have you looked at the output of `print(service.get_logs())`? Check out our [troubleshoot and debugging documentation here](https://review.learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-troubleshoot-deployment?branch=pr-en-us-124666) for other things you can try

Comment: Thanks @gopal. It was version mismatch which was causing the error. The default enviroment provided by Azure was having spark 3.0.0 version but for deployment only 1 environment was available which had spark 2.4.0 version.